# Переопределение метода интерфейса io.Reader

Tags: golang

Требуется зашифровать tcp соединение. Пытаюсь переопределись метод Read у объекта conn net.Conn

```
type Stream struct {
    conn net.Conn
    alg  algorithms.CipherAlgorithm
}

func (s *Stream) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    len, err := buf.ReadFrom(s.conn)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    p, err = s.alg.Decrypt(buf.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return int(len), err
}

func (s *Stream) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    ciphertext, err := s.alg.Encrypt(p)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return s.conn.Write(ciphertext)
}
```

Когда пытаюсь прочитать из сокета сообщение и декодировать json

```
encriptedConnection := encription.NewStream(conn, &algorithms.DES{symmetricKey})
var credentials struct{ Login, Password string }
err = json.NewDecoder(encriptedConnection).Decode(&credentials)
if err != nil {
  log.Println(err.Error())
}
```

получаю такую ошибку

```
2018/04/03 19:59:17 invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value
```

вопрос в том как изменить то что прочитано из tcp сокета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас тут две проблемы:

1 Вы вычитываете все доступные данные из соединения, без учета ёмкости входящего среда p. Если у вас кодированные и декодированные данные позволяют делать декодирование байт в байт, без изменения длины вам нужно делать примерно следующее

```
var buf = make([]byte, len(p))
len, err = conn.Read(buf)
```

Чтобы вычитывать только нужный объём данных и не терять их хвост, если вышестоящий читатель передаст буфер маленькой длины.

2 В строке

```
p, err = s.alg.Decrypt(buf.Bytes())
```

[]byte - это не массив, а структура данных: указатель на массив, длина, ёмкость.

В этой строке вместо того чтобы записать данные в исходный срез и исходный массив в присваиваете p новую структуру, которая указывает на новый массив, но поскольку p передается копированием (в go все параметры передаются копированием по значению, в т.ч. указатели - тоже копируются). То вызывающая функция о новом массиве ничего не знает. Тут вам нужно делать что-то вроде:

```
p2, err := s.alg.Decrypt(buf.Bytes())
copy(p, p2)
```

Ну или Decrypt делать аналогично ридеру - чтобы он сразу данные в нужный срез писал.